# Can someone help me understand the time and space complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, optimization, space-complexity, python

Can anyone help me understand the time and space complexity here? I know `zip()` is *O(1)* and `sorted()` is *O(n)*. The loop has the operation `min()` inside but is operating on just 2 values so is that also *O(1)*? If so then every operation in the loop is *O(1)* so the overall time complexity is *O(n)* correct? For space, `z` could grow to n as `a` and `b` grow to n as well so space is *O(n)*?

```
a = [3, 1, 2]
b = [1, 2, 3]
c = 4
def foo(a: list[int], b: list[int], c: int) -> int:
    ans = 0
    if not a:
        return ans
    z = sorted(zip(a, b), reverse=True)
    for x, y in z:
        if c > 0:
            x = min(x, c)
            ans += x * y
            c -= x
    return ans
```

Comment: What's $n\phantom{}$?

Comment: `a` and `b`. Is there a better way to ask that shows those to be _n_

Comment: The notation $O(n)$ only makes sense if $n$ is an integer (or at least a real number). `a` and `b` are lists.

Comment: Oh, okay. So I mean the size of `a` and `b`. So if the input size, which is the list length, grows to infinity then the behavior of the function as depicted on the graph is telling of the efficiency of the function.

Comment: *`sorted()`* $\in O(n)$? The time required by [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) is bounded *below* by the number of items. Please substantiate your proposition that is an upper bound, too.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own question.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `sorted()` really takes time $O(n)$, then the time and space complexities are indeed $O(n)$. Hoewever there are some catches.

You say that the zip function takes $O(1)$ time. This is technically true, but you should be aware that zip is **not** creating a list that contains pairs of elements from `a` and `b` but just returning an **iterator** to these pairs. Going through the list implicitly returned by this iterator takes $O(n)$ time, even just to construct it (e.g., `list(zip(a,b))`). In your particular case this doesn't really matter since the time complexity will be $\Omega(n)$ anyway.

You say that `sorted()` takes $O(n)$ time. This is not impossible, but it's at least suspicious (have you checked in the python documentation/implementation?). There is no algorithm that can sort a list of $n$ elements in time $O(n)$ by only performing comparisons. The implementation of `sorted()` would need to be particularly clever and recognize that you are sorting small integers.

Probably `sorted()` just takes $O(n \log n)$ time and $O(n)$ space, which would result in the same overall time and space complexities for your algorithm.

Comment: Wow, I have looked at `sorted()` and I knew it was _O(nlogn)_ due to TimSort. I apologize for the confusion as I forgot. The iterator part makes sense. And just to clarify then you are saying both overall time and space are _O(n)_ but just explaining a bit further why

Comment: If `sorted()` takes time $O(n \log n)$ then the time complexity is $O(n \log n)$ and the space complexity is $O(n)$.

Comment: Final question, and thanks for all your help. So even though it is looping through the sorted iterator of length _n_, it is still _O(nlogn)_? I would have thought _O(n)_ at that point.

Comment: If you're just asking about the complexity of the loop **after** the list has been sorted, then it's $O(n)$. If you're asking about the complexity of the whole algorithm then its $O(n \log n)$ since you're spending  $\Theta(n \log n)$ time (in the worst-case) just to sort the list.

Comment: Awesome, that is what I thought. Thanks! I upvoted but it can't be seen apparently.